# Override the action listener on the X button

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I have an internal frame which has my customer `JPanel`. In my customer `JPanel`, I added two panels which is from the outside source.
One of these has button to close the panel. However when I clicked it, it is no effect. How can I make the action listener on the button?

```
public class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame{

private PDFJPanel panel=null;


public MyInternalFrame(File file) {
     super("Test" + file.getName(), true, true, true, true);
     panel=new PDFJPanel(file);
     this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }
}
```

There is my customer JPanel

```
    public class PDFJPanel extends JPanel {    
        private JPanel jpAnnotation=null;
        private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        private File thisFile=null;
        private PDFNotesBean bean=null;
        private CommentPanel commentPane=null; 

    public PDFJPanel(File file) {
        thisFile=file;
        getJPanel();
    }


     public void getJPanel() {                   
          this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());             
          this.add(getPDFNotesBean(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

          commentPane= bean.getCommentPanel();         
          bean.getCommentPanelNotes().getjcbHideComments().setVisible(false);    
          //this code can get the button
          bean.getCommentPanelNotes().getToolbar().getCloseButton();


          //Right size of the Panel
          JPanel rightPanel=new JPanel();
          rightPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());           
          rightPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);                

          jpAnnotation=new JPanel();                         
          JButton btnUnderline =new JButton(new ImageIcon ("../UnderlineIcon.gif"));
          btnUnderline.setSize(50, 260);
          btnUnderline.setAlignmentX(JButton.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

          jpAnnotation.add(btnUnderline);         

          rightPanel.add(jpAnnotation, BorderLayout.NORTH ); 
          rightPanel.add((Component) commentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
          this.add(rightPanel,  BorderLayout.EAST );
        }
   }
```

Comment: Where do you add the `ActionListener` to the `JButton`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a shot in the dark.

```
jpAnnotation.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JFrame myInternalFrame= (JFrame)SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        myInternalFrame.remove(PDFJPanel.this);
        myInternalFrame.invalidate();
        myInternalFrame.validate();
        myInternalFrame.repaint();
    }
});
```

Comment: -1, for not following Java naming conventions. Variable names do NOT start with an upper case character. Also, the basic code when adding/removing a component from a visible GUI when using Swing is revalidate() and repaint().

Comment: @camickr What do you mean naming conventions? I just used OP variable names. As for the `GUI` part ,my code works just fine. `invalidate(); validate();` it's the same as `((JComponent) getContentPane()).revalidate()`. I think your downvote is undue.

Comment: The OP does not use any variable names for the MyInternalFrame class. You made up the variable name and are not following standards. Your code looks like you are trying to invoke a static method of the MyInternalFrame class. Yes, your code may work, but this is a Swing question, not an AWT question. Swing is different than AWT and you should be suggesting Swing conventions. We spend too much time answering questions because people don't know the difference between AWT and Swing.

Comment: Ok thnx for replying.

Comment: @camickr, Sorry, I am fairly new to Java. Would you give me example I am not following Java naming conventions in my code. Thanks.

Comment: @user819774, your naming conventions are ok. yannis used incorrect naming conventions when he first answered the question. He has since fixed the code example to use correct conventions.